# How to enter the dynamically added row contents to a database

Tags: javascript, php

```js
     <script>
         var i=0;
    currentRow = null;
                                $("button#savebutton").click(function(){   
                                        
                                    var cat = $("#cat-list").val();
                                    var display = $("#displayname").val();
                                    var subcat = $("#subcat-list").val(); 
                                    var order = $("#privilage").val();        
                                    i++;
                                    var new_row = "<tr id='row"+i+"' class='info'><td class='cat'>" + cat + "</td><td class='display'>" + display + "</td><td class='type'>" + subcat +"</td><td>"+order +"</td><td><span class='editrow'><a class='fa fa-edit' href='javascript: void(0);'>Edit</a></span></td><td><span class='deleterow'><a class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' href=''>Delete</a></span></tr>";
                                    if(currentRow){
                                   
                          $("table tbody").find($(currentRow)).replaceWith(new_row);
                                      currentRow = null;
                                     }
                                     else{
                                     $("table tbody").append(new_row);
                                     }
                                     
                                });

                            $(document).on('click', 'span.deleterow', function () {
                                    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
                                   return false;
                            });
                            $(document).on('click', 'span.editrow', function () {
         currentRow= $(this).parents('tr');                  
                       
           // $("#minAmt").val($(this).closest('tr').find('td.minAmt').text());
                            //$("#maxAmt").val($(this).closest('tr').find('td.maxAmt').text());
                           // $("#type").val($(this).closest('tr').find('td.type').text());
                            });
          </script>
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="POST" action=""/>
    <label>Category</label>
    <input type="text" id="cat-list"/></br>
    <label>Display</label>
    <input type="text" id="displayname"/></br>
    <label>SubCategory</label>
    <input type="text" id="subcat-list"/></br>
    <label>Privilage</label>
    <input type="text" id="privilage"/></br>
    </form>
    <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="form-actions btnzone">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success savebtn" style="padding: 6px 12px;margin-left: 40%;" id="savebutton"  ><i class="icon-check-sign" aria-hidden="false"></i>Add</button>
    
   </div>
  </div>
  </form>
  <form  class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="chargestableForm">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <table id="pTable" class="table table-hover" width="100%" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px; height:10px;" >
                  <thead style="background-color:#CCE5FF">
                       <tr>
           
                          <th>Category</th>
                          <th>DisplayName</th>
                          <th>Subcategory</th> 
                          <th>Order</th>         
                          <th colspan=2>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
       <tbody>     
                         </tbody>
            </table>
     
           </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Context:The code is to enter the dynamically added row contents to the database.When clicking the add button the input details are appeared as a row when again clicking the add button next row is added and that row contents are editable.When editing, the contents are updated within the row itself.So I want to enter the row contents to a database.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Where is the PHP code to update your database?

Comment: This is updating within the html table itself not database.I want to enter the these contents to a database.

Comment: So you want to enter the details in the input boxes and when you click add, you want it to appear in the HTML table but also update the database?

Comment: This is too broad, first you need to make an ajax call when you add a row and you need to write a php script to process that ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<script>
var i = 0;
currentRow = null;
$("button#savebutton").click(function() {

  var cat = $("#cat-list").val();
  var display = $("#displayname").val();
  var subcat = $("#subcat-list").val();
  var order = $("#privilage").val();
  i++;


  //Inserting first row to the table with edit and delete button  
  var new_row = "<tr id='row" + i + "' class='info'><td class='cat'>" + cat + "</td><td class='display'>" + display + "</td><td class='type'>" + subcat + "</td><td>" + order + "</td><td><span class='editrow'><a class='fa fa-edit' href='javascript: void(0);'>Edit</a></span></td><td><span class='deleterow'><a class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' href=''>Delete</a></span></tr>";

  //Appending the new row to the table                         

  if (currentRow) {
    $("table tbody").find($(currentRow)).replaceWith(new_row);
    currentRow = null;
  } else {
    $("table tbody").append(new_row);
  }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new .php file which will query the database. What you are doing now is all client side, you can use ajax in jquery to that new created file.php and send the data via ajax hence you will not have to reload the page, and the data will be sent onclick